# Pointer of Array conditional sum qty

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a question about how to make an iteration. I want to place a total row after each item in the array if the next element in the array matches a specific condition. Spesific conditions have logic like this

the data like this

[image]

if i request a qty for example = 60 the result i hope like this

you can see

> `data[2]` = 01/03/2020 just took 10 out of 40

[image]

```
$iter = new \ArrayIterator($values);
$sum = 0;
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    $nextValue = $iter->current();
    $iter->next(); 
    $nextKey = $iter->key();
    if(condition) {
       $sum += $value;
    }
}
dd($iter);
```

---

[image]

how to make this logic work on php language/ laravel?

Comment: What's the issue with your code?

Comment: i dont know how to doing that logic

Comment: When/how are you supposed to make the request? (of 60 in your example)

Comment: i made a request quantity in form html, and in backend, I break it down by qty by date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following logic might help you on your way:

```
<?php
$stock = [
    '01/01/2020' => 20,
    '01/02/2020' => 30,
    '01/03/2020' => 40
];

showStatus($stock, 'in stock - before transaction');

$demand = 60;

foreach ($stock as $key => $value) {
    if ($value <= $demand) {
        $stock[$key] = 0;
        $supplied[$key] = $value;
        $demand -= $value;
    } else {
        $stock[$key] -= $demand;
        $supplied[$key] = $value - ($value - $demand);
        $demand = 0;
    }
}

showStatus($supplied, 'supplied');
showStatus($stock, 'in stock - after transaction');


function showStatus($arr = [], $msg = '')
{
    echo $msg;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
    echo '</pre>';
}

?>

**Output:**

in stock - before transaction

Array
(
    [01/01/2020] => 20
    [01/02/2020] => 30
    [01/03/2020] => 40
)

supplied

Array
(
    [01/01/2020] => 20
    [01/02/2020] => 30
    [01/03/2020] => 10
)

in stock - after transaction

Array
(
    [01/01/2020] => 0
    [01/02/2020] => 0
    [01/03/2020] => 30
)
```

Working [demo](https://3v4l.org/v8rjF)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood you correctly but this might help:

```
$values = [
    '01/01/2020' => 20,
    '01/02/2020' => 30,
    '01/03/2020' => 40
];

$demand = 60;
$total  = array_sum($values);
$decrease = $total - $demand; //(20+30+40) - 60 = 30
$last_key = array_keys($values,end($values))[0]; //Is 01/03/2020 in this case
$values[$last_key] -= $decrease; //Decrease value with 30 calulated above
```

**Would output:**

```
Array
(
    [01/01/2020] => 20
    [01/02/2020] => 30
    [01/03/2020] => 10
)
```

Comment: yeah its work too,but static, i need something search with the conditional not in last key, maybe demand just 40, and get values 01/01/2020 and 01/02/2020, if i try this in that situation, the result (can be a minus). but thanks to help me, I am very grateful